# Parallel.Invoke the same method for a list of objects

Tags: .net, parallel-extensions

I have a class MyClass with a method MyMethod. For every MyClass instance in a list of MyClass instances i want to invoke MyMethod and have them run in a separate thread. I am using .NET 4.0 and the Parallel extensions.

Comment: do you really mean "separate thread", or do you just mean "as much in parallel as possible"?

Answer (score 5):

```
Parallel.ForEach(MyClassList, myclass => myclass.MyMethod());
```

Note that this won't necessarily run every invocation in a separate thread; it'll use the available thread pool to try to achieve an appropriate level of parallelism.
It is, however, the equivalent of running all of those `MyMethod` invocations in a big `Parallel.Invoke`, which appears to be what you're looking for.